# Armazenando de um caractere no vetor

Tags: c

Por algum motivo, o programa não está guardando o caractere no vetor, como deveria ser armazenado, ele tá pulando o primeiro caractere. Por exemplo:

```
// Declarando o vetor

char novosValores[4] = {0};

scanf("%c %c %c %c", &novosValores[0], &novosValores[1], &novosValores[2], &novosValores[3]);
```

Segue a imagem: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Basta por um espaço antes do primeiro `%c`. Como você não pôs, ele está lendo a quebra de linha e colocando no primeiro caracter

Comment: Qual o código que está para cima do `scanf("%c %c %c %c" , ...)` ? Tem outras leituras feitas com `scanf` ? se sim quais ?

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou bastante!

Comment: Não tem não, Isac, obrigado por comentar, consegui resolver com o que foi dito pelo Jefferson.

Comment: Se conseguiu resolver dessa forma, aproveite e coloque a solução como resposta para poder ajudar outras pessoas que tenham o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 1):

A função scanf utiliza um buffer para obter o input. O utilizador ao introduzir o input num terminal é guardado num buffer. A função scanf lê os carateres desse buffer.

O que acontece no teu exemplo é que estás a introduzir, após o 4, a sequência de caracteres

```
"\nE C A F\n"
```

Assim o primeiro carater que a função scanf lê é `'\n'`.

Um espaço em branco no formato da scanf, diz para a função saltar espaço em branco "whitespace" (`\n \r` espaços tabs, etc.). Desta forma, devia começar o string the formato com um espaço em branco para saltar o "whitespace" e ler o character que você pretende.